# ssh disable password authentication

Tags: sshd, openssh

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I uncomment option `PasswordAuthentication no` and restart the service via `service sshd reload`. But password authentication is still available. Why?

Comment: Is _password_ authentication still available, or is password-based _keyboard-interactive_ authentication available?  What is the setting in `sshd_config` of `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` ?

Comment: @user4556274 it's commented `#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes`.

Comment: Commented entries typically reflect the default setting, so this may be enabled unless you have edited it.  Try setting `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` and `UsePAM` explicitly to `No` and test.  Both of these settings (in addition to `PasswordAuthentication`) may affect password-based authentication.

Comment: @user4556274 now it worked, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debug log (run `ssh` with `-vvv` arguments) would give you more clue about what is going on in the connection.

The `password` authentication is not the only one which can prompt you for some kind of password. There is always `keyboard-interactive`, which behaves very similarly and is usually used by PAM. It is controlled by the `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` option, which defaults to `yes`. If you want to disable it, you need to put this option with `no` into the configuration explicitly.

Also do not disable PAM (`UsePAM`). It is not used only for authentication, but also for setting up session of the user and other steps around authentication. It might work for you now, but it might break in future or for somebody else who will be using different system.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about default values, e.g. the default entry for option `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` is `#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes`. IMO that means `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` is set to `no` by default. But in this case it is set to yes by default. For the `PasswordAuthentication` option the meaning is opposite, that's realy confusing.

Comment: Nope. The default value is written (commented out) in the configuration file by default. But you can verify that from the manual page for `sshd_config`, where it is white on black.

Comment: But `PasswordAuthentication` option is by default `#PasswordAuthentication no`, so in your opinion I don't have to uncomment it? But man page says I have to set or uncomment this option if I want to have this property enabled.

Comment: Yes, if it is so and if it corresponds with the manual page for you.

Comment: That make no sense. That is really inconsistent, like `#OptionA yes` and `#OptionB no` and the meaning is opposite in both ways, so that option A is by default no and option B is set to no as well.

Comment: Configuration file is not a coloring book to just commend and uncomment stuff by random. If you want to make a change, you should really know why you do that. The default commented options are there just for a reference and say "hey, this value is used if you will not put this option here".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61071/discussion-between-holderlin-and-jakuje).